# How does console.log get an error's stack when neither toString or valueOf return the stack?

Tags: javascript

```
(new Error('test')).toString() // 'Error: test'

(new Error('test')).valueOf() // Error('test')

(new Error('test')).stack // 'Error: test\n at <anonymous>:1:2'

console.log(new Error('test')) // Prints 'Error: test\n at <anonymous>:1:2'
```

Obviously, `console.log` is getting the stack.

```
Error.prototype.toString = () => 'toString';
Error.prototype.valueOf = () => 'valueOf';
const err = new Error('test');
err.stack = 'stack';

console.log(err); // Prints 'stack'
```

Why does `console.log` get the stack? A related question is, why doesn't `Error.prototype.toString` return the stack? It seems like a convoluted design to have `console.log` handle `Error` objects differently.

Also, are stuff like this documented somewhere? It doesn't seem to be here: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: To anyone who considers editing this question, it's worth noting that while I see the specified behavior in Chrome console, it actually isn't reproduced when using a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser implements console.log differently. For example, `console.log(new Error('test'))` in Safari prints `undefined`; so it's really up to the browser vendor how they want to implement it.

However, the `Error` object implements a `toString` method that is part of the ECMAScript spec, so browsers have to comply with that spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.4.4